# High currents LED switcher circiut for WS2811?

Tags: led, driver, ws2811

I am making one High Amp for WS2811 RGB LED driver in range 2 Amp, SO  base on it's Datasheet the driver working by this way:

[image]

there are some switcher circuit similar to this :
[image]

But this kind of circuit how had 150 mA limitation, i need to more current for light power RGB LED's and  need led driver which is working with WS2811 IC outputs. SO what kind of circuits are proper for this driver?

Thanks a lot for your attention.

Comment: So, you want to build your own version of a WS2811 capable of sinking 2 amps?

Comment: Are you looking for a power supply, please be more specific. You may want to re-read the rules on asking questions.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar project, using a high current LED driver IC and a separate PWM generator.

At these currents, linear regulators are too wasteful and would run too hot (a LDO with just 0.4V overhead would have to dissipate 40mW), and you need fairly exact current control, so most of these driver ICs use a buck or buck-boost topology, with external inductors (plus flyback diode) and capacitors.

I'm using a quad-channel driver, the [LT3476](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/3476fb.pdf) in combination with an [LT8500](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/8500fa.pdf) PWM generator. For you, a triple-channel driver might be better suited (I have RGBW LEDs).

The datasheets include an application note that includes a schematic and rules for component selection and board layout. It's still an intermediate level project, but doable.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on how many LEDs you are going to drive. If the current will not exceed the max for the OUTx pin of the WS2811 use schematics one. If the current exceeds the maximum allowed, drive it via the transistor.